# tx_News, Date Menu with Archive no constraint does not open archived news

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

News system 5.2.0, TYPO3 7.6.11

**Date Menu with Archive no constraint**

If i click in the menu on a date with archived news it shows "Keine Nachrichten verfügbar."

Thanks for any hint?

Comment: Please provide some more detail: what is your page configuration (i.e. which pages with which plugins), how did you configure news (provide TS snippets or screenshots of the plugin forms) etc. There are many things that could be wrong, and we need to rule them out one by one. That gets a lot easier when we know what exactly you did :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to help here because so less information is provided! Anyway I try:

The message "*keine nachrichten ist verfügbar*" is shown by a `List view` and I **guess** this is configured differently then the date menu! You need to allow archived news as well in the list module!

Comment: Dear Georg, thanks for your answer.

That is right, in List view i did allow archived and it works.

But on my Archive page with List View (with only archived) i have also Date Menu with Archive no constraint.

**And here i get all news with the Date Menu.**